# how to protect server side script and hidden which are writing with Node.js

Tags: node.js, xss

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'meusername',
    password : 'secret',
    database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
 if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Above code have some private information like database name, user, password and SQL query too. I am new in `node.js` and curious to know if a script which have been written on Node.js will save in .js format and what if it contain server side script too? I mean how can it be safe/hidden like `.php` and `aspx`?

I would be more than happy if someone explain me in detail and also share some tips to prevent XSS attacks on Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Your question breaks down into two parts:

1. Why is server-side JavaScript code save? (it won't be sent to the user)
2. Something about XSS

---

## Why is server-side JavaScript code save

You have to execute the code on the server to run it. Like

```
node index.js
```

Like with PHP and asp.net, the code is then run on said server. And likewise only the **output** generated by those scripts/executables will be sent to the client/browser.

The code snippet you posted doesn't even open a listening socket. So no client can connect to it.

You should also have no HTTP Server that serves the folder in which your script are stored. In conclusion: Since the files will never be transferred to the client, you don't need to worry about the secret data that is stored there.

## Something about XSS

Your question about XSS is pretty vague. The concept of XSS basically breaks down to:

> Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks are a type of injection, in which malicious scripts are injected into otherwise benign and trusted web sites. ([Source](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)))

So as long as the client/user is unable to make the server print unvetted data, you are save.